Can cloud9 ide be deployed on another hosting server?
There is something I don't understand that got me confused, I saw a link which cloud9 ide was hosted on. What I don't understand is how this is achievable. below is the image of the link.
screenshot
I have checked online for a better understanding on how this is done but couldn't get any help. So can a cloud9 ide be hosted on another hosting server? And the file extension is even an html, how is this possible? I will be glad to learn from the experts on this, and if there's a documentation, article or tutorial on this, I will be glad to learn from it...
Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
